# Laravel eloquent recors newer then 5 minutes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon, laravel-query-builder

This may look like a doublepost but it isn't.
I am trying to see if a user has posted a topic in the past 5 minutes and i tried million codes to check but somehow my code always counts 1 or more.

This is the solution i currently have:

```
public function allowedToPostTopic() {
    $count = Topic::where([
        ['user_id', '=', $this->id],
        ['created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes($this->role->topic_delay)]
    ])->count();

    if ($count == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

$this->role->topic_delay = 5 i know that for sure (also tested this with var_dumb)

i tried to change > in < since it's confusing me and i tried lots of other ways like:

```
 NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

But that doesn't work either :(

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: 1 hint to debug is to simply get the topics that is returned by your query so replace `->count()` with `->get()` you can dd the result and inspect the behavior. One other reason there might be issue is the timezone that Carbon is using, as against the timezone that the datetime in the db uses.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi This is what i get returned 2017-07-21 20:32:16 - 2017-07-21 20:17:05 (left is the topic created_at and right is the carbon date) and yes the carbon now date is wrong

Comment: I solved it by filling in the correct time zon in app/config.php sorry for my stupidness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following for troubleshooting;

1. Enable query logging, grab the result of the query and try running it in your database application, tamper with it until you get the correct results
2. Try outputting carbon as a datetime stamp with the format function
3. Verify the data in the db is correct
4. Step through it with xdebug if all else fails and use the evaluator

I wouldn't expect it to be a matter of setting the date property on the model because I'm pretty sure that's alreAdy handled, but might be worthwhile checking over the model too to make sure there isn't anything weird there.

Comment: This is what i get returned 2017-07-21 20:32:16 - 2017-07-21 20:17:05 (left is the topic created_at and right is the carbon date) that means the carbon date is wrong.

Comment: I solved it by filling in the correct time zon in app/config.php sorry for my stupidness

Comment: Thats not stupidness, its another thing you have learnt embrace it and anticipate more things to learn....